# How to use the Wayback Machine API with URL query string?

Tags: json, api, parameters, urlencode, url-encoding

I'm trying to get information with the wayback machine API.

The webpage I'm testing the API with is :

`http://www.ifop.com/?option=com_publication&type=poll&id=3367`

As you can see here, the webpage is already archived :

`https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.ifop.com/?option=com_publication&type=poll&id=3367`

So when I'm using the API :

`http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=http://www.ifop.com/?option=com_publication&type=poll&id=3367`

I should get my information but the API answer is empty as if the webpage wasn't archived...

`{"archived_snapshots":{}}`

I tried to replace `&` with `&amp;` but it's still empty...

So my question is : how to use the Wayback Machine API with URL query string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**
The ampersands, even in `&amp;`, are parsed as additional parameters to the API rather than as part of the `url` parameter.

**Solution:**
Use `%26` to encode the ampersand.  Similarly encode the rest of the URL.

Your request becomes:
`http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifop.com%2F%3Foption%3Dcom_publication%26type%3Dpoll%26id%3D3367`

Comment: Oh it was that simple ? Sorry and thank you very much ! :)